# rails4: multiple image upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array, carrierwave

I am trying to upload multiple images using carrierwave, and everything works fine when I am selecting multiple images at once(shift+select), but in my case I am also interested in uploading files item by item to show them in a thumbnail.

The problem is when I select one image at a time, only the last image gets uploaded after submitting the form

```
 <%= f.fields_for :product_attachment do |p| %>
  <div class="field" id="uploads-form">
    <%= p.label :image %><br>
    <%= p.file_field :image,multiple:true,name:"product_attachments[image][]",id:"files"%>
 <output id="list"></output>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

The script:

```
<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

// Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

  // Only process image files.
  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();

  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
    };
  })(f);

  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
 }

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: Each time you select a single image, you are only selecting a single file that is why only the last selected is submitted. Lets say you have a file selected, subsequently selecting a different single image doesn't add the second image alongside the first. Selecting a second single image just replaces whatever is there.

Comment: How can I assign the separated images and pass them to the array, the same way as if they were group-selected?